# Can I import a Oracle Database in multi-boot?

Tags: windows, oracle, ubuntu

What do I need to know to do the process below?

1: Sending query statements from Ubuntu to Windows
2: Querying the database on Windows
3: Receiving processing results from Ubuntu to Windows

--reference--
I am in Ubuntu and Windows 10 multi-boot environment.
I have an oracle 19c database on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to migrate your database to an [official docker container](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase) or to Virtualbox/VMWare VM, so you could use the same container in both environments.

Comment: Wow! I never imagined the answers would run so fast. Thank you!